# C++ Battleships free space function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a game of battleships in which the computer randomly lays the battleships on the board.

Battleships cannot be placed one on top of the other or right next to each other.
I built a function to check this and return true if free space is available, but for some reason the program still puts lays the ships against the rules. It doesn't happen every time, but it still happens.

Here's the function that checks for free space:

```
bool Game2::CheckPlace(int row, int column, DIRECTION direct, Battleship ship)//this function checks if a ship can be layed at the coordinates it recieved.
{
    if (board[row][column] != '_' || board[row][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1][column] != '_' || board[row - 1][column - 1] != '_' || board[row][column - 1] != '_' || board[row + 1][column - 1] != '_' || board[row + 1][column] != '_' || board[row + 1][column + 1] != '_')
        return false;
    if (direct == horizontal)//for horizontal direction
    {
        if (10 - column < ship.GetLength())//if there is no space left for the ship.
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ship.GetLength(); ++i)//this loop creates a kind of a block that moves together to find surrounding ships.
        {
            if (row == 0 && column == 0 && (board[row + 1][column + i] != '_' || board[row + 1][column + 1 + i] != '_' || board[row][column + 1 + i] != '_'))//top left corner
                return false;
            if (row == 9 && column == 0 && (board[row - 1][column + i] != '_' || board[row - 1][column + 1 + i] != '_') || board[row][column + 1 + i] != '_')//bottom left corner
                return false;
            if (row > 0 && row < 9 && column > 0 && column < 9 && board[row][column + 1 + i] != '_' || board[row + 1][column + 1 + i] != '_' || board[row + 1][column + i] != '_' || board[row + 1][column - 1 + i] != '_' || board[row][column - 1 + i] != '_' || board[row - 1][column - 1 + i] != '_' || board[row - 1][column + i] != '_' || board[row - 1][column + 1 + i] != '_')//middle of the board
                return false;
            if (row == 0 && column > 0 && column < 9 && (board[row][column - 1 + i] != '_' || board[row][column + i] != '_' || board[row][column + 1 + i] != '_' || board[row + 1][column - 1 + i] != '_' || board[row + 1][column + i] != '_' || board[row + 1][column + 1 + i] != '_'))
                return false;
            if (row == 9 && column > 0 && column < 9 && (board[row - 1][column - 1 + i] != '_' || board[row - 1][column + i] != '_' || board[row - 1][column + 1 + i] != '_' || board[row][column - 1 + i] != '_' || board[row][column + i] != '_' || board[row][column + 1 + i] != '_'))
                return false;
            if (column = 0 && row > 0 && row < 9 && (board[row + 1][column + i] != '_' || board[row + 1][column + 1 + i] != '_' || board[row][column + 1 + i] != '_' || board[row - 1][column + i] != '_' || board[row - 1][column + 1 + i] != '_'))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (direct == vertical)
    {
        if (10 - row < ship.GetLength())//if there is no space left for the ship.
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ship.GetLength(); ++i)//this loop creates a kind of a block that moves together to find surrounding ships.
        {
            if (row == 0 && column == 0 && (board[row + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column] != '_'))
                return false;
            if (row == 0 && column == 9 && (board[row + i][column - 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column - 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column] != '_'))
                return false;
            if (row == 0 && column > 0 && column < 9)
                if (board[row + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column] != '_' || board[row + i][column - 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column - 1] != '_')
                    return false;
            if (column == 0 && row > 0 && row < 9 && (board[row + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column] != '_' || board[row - 1 + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row - 1 + i][column] != '_'))
                return false;
            if (column == 9 && row > 0 && row < 9 && (board[row + i][column - 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column - 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column] != '_' || board[row - 1 + i][column - 1] != '_' || board[row - 1 + i][column] != '_'))
                return false;
            if (row > 0 && row < 9 && column > 0 && column < 9)
                if ((board[row + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column] != '_' || board[row + i][column - 1] != '_' || board[row + 1 + i][column - 1] != '_' || board[row - 1 + i][column + 1] != '_' || board[row - 1 + i][column] != '_' || board[row - 1 + i][column - 1] != '_'))
                    return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

And here's a photo of an example output:
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Why don't you use a temporary board which is a copy of the original board, add the battleship by adding each item to the temp-board with tmp_board[x][y] += '_' and then check if the each value of the battleship is not '_'.

Comment: `if (column = 0`  should be `==`. A decent compiler would warn on this with warnings enabled.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried debugging it line by line many times, but it seems that every time i did it the battleships were layed  correctly. I cant predict when the error is happening.

Comment: @user5633902 if your program involves random numbers, you should display the seed of each run so you can keep and reuse those which trigger the bug.

Comment: @interjay Thank you! Next time i'll take the warnings under consideration and not just the errors. Lesson learnd!

Comment: @interjay By the way, any recommendations for a good compiler? VS didn't seem to warn me about it.

Comment: @HaimLeshem It is probably just compiler flags. Add "-Wall -Werror" to compiler settings/flags and it should be reporting everything.

Answer (score 0):

@interjay already answered your question pointing out the error in the condition:

```
if ( column = 0 ... // should be ==
```

As many others said, remember to always enable all the warnings your compiler can rise. You could also try to  write the literals first:

```
if ( 0 = column ... // that's an error every compiler can catch
```

The main reason I wrote this answer is that I'd like to show you a different (maybe more readable and less error prone) algorithm to achive your task, if I may.

Think about the ship and its sorrounding water as a rectangle in the sea (board). To check all the cells inside a rectangle is easy, it can be done in a nested loop. To correctly define the vertices of the rectangle of search may be trickier, but not too much.

I guess I've figured out how you store the data about the ships (the needed ones at least), so this snippet of code should work:

```
const int rows = 10;
const int cols = 10;

bool CheckPlace(int row, int column, DIRECTION direct, Battleship ship) {

    // check if the top left corner of the ship is inside the board
    if ( row < 0  ||  row >= rows  ||  column < 0  || column >= cols )
        return false;

    int r_min = row,            // temporary top side of the rectangle
        c_min = column,         // temporary left side
        r_max = row + 2,        // temporary bottom side
        c_max = column + 2;     // temporary right side

    // update top and left size if there is enough space
    if ( r_min > 0 ) --r_min;
    if ( c_min > 0 ) --c_min;

    // use ship length and direction to update values for right and bottom side
    // max values are one past the border of the rectangle
    if ( horizontal == direct ) 
        c_max += ship.GetLength() - 1;
    else 
        r_max += ship.GetLength() - 1;

    // check if the bottom rigth corner of the ship is outside the board
    if ( r_max > rows + 1 ||  c_max > cols + 1 )
        return false;

    // clip the rectangle if the ship is near the border
    if ( r_max > rows )
        --r_max;
    if ( c_max > cols )
        --c_max;

    // check inside the rectangle
    for ( int i = r_min; i < r_max; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = c_min; j < c_max; ++j ) {
            if ( '_' != board[i][j] )
                return false;
        }   
    }   

    // open water
    return true;
}
```